# Using \ifstrequal in a fontspec macro

Tags: macros, fontspec, etoolbox

Here is my Minimal Failing Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,etoolbox}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\Stretch[1]{
  \ifstrequal{#1}{narrow}{0.6}{}
  \ifstrequal{#1}{wide}{1.5}{}
}

Normal. {\addfontfeature{FakeStretch=\Stretch{narrow}} Narrow.} Normal.
Normal. {\addfontfeature{FakeStretch=\Stretch{wide}} Wide.} Normal.

\end{document}
```

(Xe)LaTeX fails with the message `Missing \endcsname inserted` because of the `\ifstrequal` macro.  Can you explain me why?  And how can I modify the `\Stretch` macro so that it works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need an expandable version of `\Stretch`. `\ifstrequal` contains definitions, thus `\ifstrequal` is not expandable.

Example for an expandable definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,etoolbox}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\Stretch@narrow}{0.6}
\newcommand*{\Stretch@wide}{1.5}
\newcommand*{\Stretch}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{Stretch@#1}{%
    \Stretch@UnknownArgument % throws error as undefined command
    1% error recovery
  }{%
    \@nameuse{Stretch@#1}%
  }
}
\makeatother

Normal. {\addfontfeature{FakeStretch=\Stretch{narrow}} Narrow.} Normal.

Normal. {\addfontfeature{FakeStretch=\Stretch{wide}} Wide.} Normal.

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The argument of `\Stretch` is taken to compose a macro `\Stretch@<argument>`, which expands to the number according to `<argument>`.

If the argument is not known, `\Stretch@<argument>` is undefined and behaves as `\relax` (side effect of `\csname` that is called by `\@nameuse`). This would trigger the error like before. As a normal error message will not work in this context, the above version of `\Stretch` uses an unknown command `\Stretch@UnknownArgument` to transport the cause of the error to the user. As error recovery the value `1` is returned.

Answer (score 3):

It probably needs to *expand* to a number, so you need to keep the tests expandable. This uses `\@car` to discard all but the first letter and then tests that against `n` or `w`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,etoolbox}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Stretch[1]{%
\if n\@car #1.\@nil 0.6\else
\if w\@car #1.\@nil 1.5\else
1\fi\fi}

\makeatother

\typeout{[\Stretch{narrow}][\Stretch{wide}][\Stretch{ll}]}

Normal. {\addfontfeature{FakeStretch=\Stretch{narrow}} Narrow.} Normal.
Normal. {\addfontfeature{FakeStretch=\Stretch{wide}} Wide.} Normal.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With `fontspec` you have available the wonderful world of LaTeX3!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \Stretch #1
 {
  \str_case:nnn { #1 }
   {
    {narrow} {0.6}
    {wide}   {1.5}
   }
  {1} % fall back case
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Normal. {\addfontfeature{FakeStretch=\Stretch{narrow}} Narrow.} Normal.
Normal. {\addfontfeature{FakeStretch=\Stretch{wide}} Wide.} Normal.

\end{document}
```

It's very easy to extend this to other keywords.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the most flexible solution, but when I copy-paste your code and run `xelatex`, I get an `! Undefined control sequence` error. Did I miss something? Do I need a more recent version of expl3? Mine is 2012/04/23.

Comment: @BertS The `expl3` bundle you have is very outdated: the present version is dated 2013/03/14